# Hot to specify number of tasks for a Dataframe join in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that I read from a SQL DB, both with 10 tasks.

Then, when I join them with `df1.join(df2)` it makes 200 tasks for the join operation and I can't understand why that is 200 and how can I change it?

For example, when working with `rdd`s, methods like `join` take `[numTasks]` parameter, but I can't find no equivalents here. Is there any reason why?

Comment: I find a lot of the things badly explained, particularly on tasks. I think how would I design it and then it seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to another value, default is 200, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options

Note that has no effect when doing broadcast-joins. If you changes this value, this will also affect the number of tasks when doing aggegation.